# Pcmanfm-qt slow scrolling

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, scrolling, pcmanfm

How Can I do that `pcmanfm-qt` scroll up and down fast, like "old" `pcmanfm` (I'm using Lubuntu 20,04 LTS official, 64bits)?

For example, Mozilla Firefox has this option:

[image: Firefox scrolling option]

Photography above is same like "new" `pcmanfm-qt` (slow scrolling or smooth scrolling and I don't like it).

Question is:

How Can I "unmark" on `pcmanfm-qt` that option (like firefox, I mean, having `pcmanfm-qt` without "smooth scrolling" as normal or "old" `pcmanfm` that it has "unmark" the smooth scrolling)?.

**Edit:**

On Lubuntu 20,04 I have `pcmanfm-qt` (slow scrolling or smooth scrolling) and I have in same system `pcmanfm` (fast scrolling and no smooth scrolling), isn't "problem" with mouse or pad, is "problem" with `pcmanfm-qt`.

Comment: Okey, I clarify that I'm using Lubuntu 20,04, I downloaded it from:

https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/

In official page it says that it has LTS until 2023, so is Lubuntu 20,04 official and question is about scrolling on pcmanfm-QT.

Comment: Yep, 20.04 & 20.04.1 are *official* and not *development* software (20.04.2 currently is *development* until it's *currently unscheduled* release in 2021).   Have you looked at the Lubuntu manual on mouse scrolling - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html

Comment: Thank you, I was reading that manual and not found solution because, new pcmanfm-qt scrolling only accept configuration per line or min 1 "wheel scroll lines". I want disabling that effect from pcmanfm-qt "smooth scrolling", like "old" pcmanfm that you can scroll up and down and does not have effect, and I want doing it on pcmanfm-qt. Cause pcmanfm-qt is slow with that effect, meanwhile "old" pcmanfm doesn't. ¿Can you understand me?.

I mean, yes scrolling but without slow effect of pcmanfm-qt, is like old pcmanfm that you can scrolling fast without slow animation or effect.

Comment: Update: On Lubuntu-lxqt with pcmanfm-qt, I was investigating and there are one option with keyboard to scroll fast (no perfect solution but it works), solution is that when you are scrolling you can press SHIFT on your keyboard and it is fast.

Comment: FYI:  You may already know this, `pcmanfm` used GTK2 libraries and is ~EOL; the developer (pcman) ported it GTK3 but it was slower & heavier (GTK3 is), so it was then ported to Qt5 where `pcmanfm-qt` is currently. It's quite possible that what you're after was easy on GTK(2/3) but dropped on Qt5 as it was required complete re-write thus dropped. You could try another OS that has LXQt (eg. opensuse tumbleweed has LXQt 15.1) and if it's identical there (I bet it is), file it as a request upstream on LXQt's github  (I never used the feature so aren't 100% sure on it sorry)